# Python subprocess formating problem with Imagemagick

Tags: python, subprocess, imagemagick

In my terminal this works:

```
magick -size 480x480 xc:black -fill white -strokewidth 2 -draw 'circle 240,240 240,0' ____test.png
```

From Python (3.9), this one does not:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(['magick', '-size', '480x480', 'xc:black', '-fill', 'white', '-strokewidth', '2', '-draw', '"circle 240,240 240,0"', '____test.png'])
```

I think it's about the quotation marks, but I really tried all variations (I think) and… error message is:

```
magick: non-conforming drawing primitive definition `circle 240,240 240,0' @ error/draw.c/RenderMVGContent/4469.
```

Help!

Comment: I think I figured it out. Not the actual answer (which I would still be intrested in) but this works:
`filterchain = 'circle 240,240 240,0'`
`subprocess.call(['magick', '-size', '480x480', 'xc:black', '-fill', 'white', '-strokewidth', '2', '-draw', filterchain, '____test.png'])`

Comment: I find answer from another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63350129/10009424). Replace `'"circle 240,240 240,0"'` with `'circle 240,240 240,0'`. That is `subprocess.call(['magick', '-size', '480x480', 'xc:black', '-fill', 'white', '-strokewidth', '2', '-draw', 'circle 240,240 240,0', '____test.png'])`